# Nest.JS JSON RPC Support

Tags: node.js, typescript, json-rpc, nestjs

I'm looking into using Nest.JS for a project, but a key requirement for my project means I have to provide a JSON-RPC API as well as the usual HTTP/Socket.io API.

Wondered if that was supported. Apparently this is the best place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest does support gRPC out of the box, you can read about it here https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/grpc but not JSON-RPC, and Im not sure if this is exposed, so basically answering to your first part of question: Nope, there is no support for JSON-RPC in nest out of the box. But the second one, the answer is: yes, you can map your controller methods to the socket/http request.

Comment: Cool, thanks. What is gRPC and how does it differ from json-rpc. Also, if there is no support for json-rpc out of the box, can it be added?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a nestjs JSON-RPC implementation now https://github.com/Insidexa/nestjs-rpc

Comment: Thx you very much for sharing, it`s my library :)